# Cómo sumar dos campos diferentes en una consulta soql

Tags: ubuntu

Estoy realizando una consulta en soql para que calcule el valor medio de dos campos numéricos H01 y H02 de un archivo json, cuyos valores son 0.6 y 0.4, respectivamente. Esta consulta obtiene un solo registro. La consulta es así:

```
query="SELECT H01,H02, $((H01 + H02))/2 AS AVERAGE WHERE pollutant = 'H6' AND DATA = '2020-05-08T00:00:00.000' AND location = 'London'"
```

Sin embargo, al ejecutar esta consulta, como valor AVERAGE sale 0, cuando tendría que salir 0.5.

¿Cómo puedo calcular este valor y, además, redondear el resultado a 3 cifras decimales? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Será que las columnas H01 y H02 están declaradas como enteras. Pon el denominador en coma flotante, 2.0 en lugar de 2.

```
query="SELECT H01,H02, $((H01 + H02))/2.0 AS AVERAGE WHERE pollutant = 'H6' AND DATA = '2020-05-08T00:00:00.000' AND location = 'London'"
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Gracias Carles por tu respuesta. Lo acabo de hacer pero continúa saliendo 0 (exactamente sale 0E-20).

Comment: Quizás se me escapa algo porque no sé qué es soql. No entiendo esa notación $(()). Pero de todas formas, dime un par de cosas: quantos refistros has en la tabla con pollutant = 'H6' y con esa DATA y esa location? Y también, cuanto valen H01 y H02 en esos registros. O sea, que resultado esperas?

Comment: SoQL es una forma de acceso a APIs que utilizan datos abiertos. Usa un lenguaje parecido a SQL, aunque no implementa todas sus herramientas (https://dev.socrata.com/). Con los datos que indico sólo tengo un registro, es una consulta que da como resultado un registro. H01 vale 0.6 y H02 vale 0.4. Lo que espero es calcular el valor medio de estos dos valores, que sería 0.5. La expresión de arriba para calcular este valor medio no realiza el cálculo, da como resultado 0.

Comment: Entonces ya no sé. Pero de todas formas, me resulta inquietante que se requieran dos paréntesis anidados después del dólar. Prueba a poner el dividido por 2-0 dentro del primer paréntesis, no?

Comment: No funciona, sigue saliendo 0. Gracias igualmente.